# why won't geom_bar() change fill color like it's supposed to in python ggplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-ggplot

I'm trying to follow the demo here:  http://blog.yhat.com/posts/aggregating-and-plotting-time-series-in-python.html  and am unable to reproduce the figure 
[image]

mine looks like this: 
[image: badmeat]

I'm using Win 8 with Python 2.7, the latest ggplot master from github (0.6.6 I think, but pip is telling me it's 0.6.5), pandas 0.16.2, numpy 1.8.1, and matplotlib 1.4.3.  I think I've correctly reproduced the code from the demo:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from ggplot import *

def floor_decade(date_value):
    "Takes a date. Returns the decade."
    return (date_value.year // 10) * 10

meat2 = meat.dropna(thresh=800, axis=1) # drop columns that have fewer than 800 observations
ts = meat2.set_index(['date'])

by_decade = ts.groupby(floor_decade).sum()

by_decade.index.name = 'year'

by_decade = by_decade.reset_index()

p1 = ggplot(by_decade, aes('year', weight='beef')) + \
    geom_bar() + \
    scale_y_continuous(labels='comma') + \
    ggtitle('Head of Cattle Slaughtered by Decade')

p1.draw()
plt.show()

by_decade_long = pd.melt(by_decade, id_vars="year")

p2 = ggplot(aes(x='year', weight='value', colour='variable'), data=by_decade_long) + \
geom_bar() + \
ggtitle("Meat Production by Decade")

p2.draw()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. Try using `fill` parameter in `ggplot` instead of `colour`. This will fill the insides of the bars with the color specified, instead of colouring the lines.
Also, you can change the lines around the bars with `colour` as a `geom_bar` parameter. The following shows both:

`p2 = ggplot(aes(x='year', weight='value', fill='variable'), data=by_decade_long) + geom_bar(colour='black') + ggtitle("Meat Production by Decade")`

[Bar Chart Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeZ7k.png)

Source: I just went through this same struggle learning ggplot for python.

Comment: Thanks.  The weird thing is, I'm pretty sure my code reproduces the sample code here (http://blog.yhat.com/posts/aggregating-and-plotting-time-series-in-python.html )--but their figure looks different.

Comment: As a side question, do you know an easy way to change the 'variable' title on the legend?

Comment: @wordsforthewise, well one way I can think of is to rename the dataframe column from `variable` to `colnamehere` or whatever name you want, like so: `by_decade_long.columns = ['year','colnamehere','value']`  I am not sure about editing the actual legend title, but this way does change the legend title to 'colnamehere'.

Answer (score 1):

For me this didn't work. 
I still had to add the argument position='stack' to geom_bar(), so `geom_bar(position='stack')` :

```
ggplot(aes(x='year', weight='value', fill='variable'), data=by_decade_long) + \
geom_bar(position='stack') + \
ggtitle("Meat Production by Decade")
```

Note that with `geom_bar(position='fill')` you will get relative scores, i.e. percentages instead of values.